# Attribute depends on other attribute

Tags: c#

I have an attribute which is dependent on another attribute i.e. it would have no effect unless the other attribute is present. Can I somehow have that whenever that attribute is added to a class, the other attribute gets added too?

For example, there is a Decorator attribute

```
public class Decorator : Attribute {
    public void draw(){}
}

public class Field : Attribute {
     public void FunctionThatIsCallingAllDecorators(){
         foreach(var attribute in GetAllDrawers()){
             attribute.draw();
         }
     }
     ...
}
```

Here decorator attribute is only useful if the class also has a field attribute, so what I want is that any class that is given a decorator attribute also gets a field attribute.

Comment: If `Field` highly depends on `Decorator`, why would you define two attribute?

Comment: @qxg It doesn't depend very highly but they do different jobs here field creates a UI field for the field in the class it is marked to and decorators are used to change various aspects of that UI field like color etc. As a result there is no meaning of a decorator without a field but whenever someone is adding a decorator they sure need a field, so it can reduce typing but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create constructor in Decorator class.
Create one variable of 'Field' and always instantiate in constructor of Decorator.

You can expose this 'Field' variable using property.